# Colorado Injury Attorneys

Tags: employment, injury

Why we need to hire a personal injury attorneys to cover a personal injury losses? How they are beneficial to cover injury losses?

Answer (score 4):

### You don’t need to hire an attorney

If you like, you can represent yourself. Just like you can build your own house, repair your own car or amputate your own limb. You only need to be a lawyer if you are representing someone else.

However, there is a saying that goes: A person representing themselves has a fool for a client. Your lawyer is a professional, you aren’t. They know what to do when the other side says “Objection, facts not in evidence” or how to correctly fill out, file and serve a pleading; do you?